# Would You hear sound if your space ship had a Collision

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, spaceships

As the title states I have a scene in my book where two ships collide in space. What I want to know is would the passengers hear the sound from inside the ship. (the ship’s hull did not breach but it was a very hard hit) I know that the vacuum of space stops sound but if the ship has air therefore a way for noise to be heard would it. The collision happened outside so I'm a bit torn to what would happen

Comment: if you want me to add more detail just ask, i made it small so the admins wont hunt me down if it's (opinion based) or (too broad)

Comment: I really hate the idea that you can't hear sounds in a space ship. If you're designing a space ship and something explodes in close proximity to the ship. Would you not have sensors interpret the light pattern of an explosion and pump it throughout the ship so crew members having dinner don't need to run to a monitor and replay events to see how far away and how big the detonation was?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as being _not about worldbuilding_. You aren't trying to build anything, merely understand how a real, physical phenomenon functions in our very real world (universe?). As such, this topic is more appropriate on the Physics SE than here.

Comment: @MikeyMouse But light and sound aren't the same thing. You could have a very loud noise that's not accompanied by any light, and you can also have very bright light without any accompanying sound. I don't think there's any way to reliably derive a sound pattern from a light pattern.

Comment: @Frostfyre so me asking a real world question is not world-building, if you check the front question page there is like five topics about the (real world) just today. My book is sci-fi and I am trying to find facts to help me world-build. So if I change it so the passengers are all wizards or something like that would the question still be closed I think not, its people like you that make this site so hard to like, the question is well received the answers are well thought out I don’t see a problem

Comment: @MikeyMouse In the real world, naval vessels don't distribute surround sound systems throughout the ship just so the crew can get a sense for how far away an anti-ship missile was when CIWS scragged it. I've heard the 'artificial sound for the crew' justification for fiction before, but it doesn't sound remotely plausible in a realistic context.

Comment: @CreedArcon I just checked the front page; all of the open questions there are about worldbuilding. You've asked, "How do sound and space work?" This is not a worldbuilding topic; it's a science topic.

Comment: wouldn't it be better served being moved to the physics se?

Comment: i have played your game admins and have followed the rules so i hope that you take it off hold

Comment: This feels like the edit was done in bad faith. The main question is still : How sound travel? To me, this is a trivial question (but maybe I misunderstood) and not related to building a world, as Frostfyre already mentioned.

Comment: @Vincent how is it bad faith i have changed my question to fit what they wanted me to (i have followed the rules to the fullest) i have even gone down their narrow view on what counts as world building, I have asked this question to help me with my book. so with the question as it is now is like manly others on this site that have been untouched by the admins so if this gets cut down then you guys have a lot of work to do with the rest. I’ve played your game followed the rules but i will take this stand so what will you do? Because to me it seems very biased

Comment: *This feels like the edit was done in bad faith.* Ya think? - The edit is a well-deserved snarky response to a really infuriating criticism. - The "World" in "WorldbuildingSE" does not denote just magical forests and distant planets. It means the world in which a story is set. Questions about unfamiliar story settings are on topic for this site, even if, in theory, the setting probably exists somewhere.

Comment: If other users think that the 5 people (including me) are wrong to close this question, they can nominate it for reopening. It only takes a handful of votes to achieve. So if the five of us are wrong, your question will be reopened. Though weekends tend to be quiet.  More info here : https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36423/273762

Comment: I attempted to reformat your question to *try* bring it more on topic. I don't know if I succeeded. You are welcome to rollback or even further revise it. I won't be offended. I did try to keep your question intact but eloborated to avoid the snark. It is frustrating but the snark can be offputting to some who would be willing to reopen the question. Trust me, you just have to roll with it :)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Absolutely.**

If there is a medium to transmit vibration such as a ship hull into the atmosphere inside, any people aboard would definitely hear the sound. Sound is just a vibration through matter, be it solid steel, water, or air. If a ship's hull is impacted, it would transmit that sound to the air inside.

All that's required is physical contact. In the same way, two astronauts in space would be able to speak to each other without radio if they touched their helmets together.

Comment: so if lets say an astronaut outside taps a on window would you hear him or would a only a hard hit would work?

Comment: Yes, you would hear them tapping. Say they tap on a window: the window will vibrate from their tapping, that vibration will vibrate the air on the other side in exactly the same way a speaker vibrates the air when it moves. Vibrating air is better known as sound.

Comment: I think its plausible that a tapping on the window might be too quiet to hear, between the thick windows and the soft layers of fabric over the knucles of the astronaut, but there would certainly be a sound.  A collision is a... less than subtle knock.

Comment: @Christoph It's actually [quadruple glazed](https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2017/04/crew-replace-cupola-window-iss/).  Only the middle two layers are pressurised - the layers either side are purely for protection.  Double-glazing doesn't keep out all sound though, because the vibrations still come through the frame.  Anyone who's had a bird fly into a window can testify to that impact noise coming through loud and clear.

Comment: @Samuel - In The Expanse books, they do the helmet-contact for some radio-less conversation. I can't remember whether you see it on the TV series - Bobbie Draper and another marine early in season two, possibly?

Comment: @CreedArcon Perhaps worth pointing out that if a passenger inside tapped on the window, an astronaut outside would *not* hear them, because there's no medium between the window and the astronaut to transmit the sound.

Comment: If there's something unrealistic about this, it's that two spaceships would get close enough to tap, but not enough to inflict serious damage to either ship.  Objects in orbit around earth easily move hundreds of meters per second, making it almost a statistical impossibility for two such objects to simply "tap" together.

Comment: Neil it’s very realistic ships HAVE collided in space present day there's a video that @DarkDust has shown us on his own question. And I never said that the ships were not damaged I just said the hull was not breached

Comment: @UselessInfoMine I haven't seen the show, but I did read some of the books a while back (pre-show). It's a common and realistic method used in stories to allow communication in vacuum.

Answer (score 7):

As @Samuel already explained, you can hear collisions if the inside is pressurized. The vibrations of the contact are transmitted through the hull to the air and this in turn to your ears.

As a real-life example, [astronauts inside ISS can hear their colleagues doing EVAs](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20886/can-astronauts-inside-iss-hear-their-crewmates-doing-evas). The astronauts inside can hear the outside astronauts moving along the hull and noises generated when they use tools (with direct contact to the hull), for example. Astronauts inside ISS can even hear the impact of micro-meteoroids.

An astronaut in a space-suit (which is a very tiny spacecraft, in a sense) is also able to [hear noises via direct contact](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/24201/can-astronauts-hear-sounds-during-space-walks-for-repairs?noredirect=1&lq=1). In some movies this is used to have two astronauts with failed communication devices talk to each other by having their helmets touch and speak. This should indeed work: your voice vibrates the air which vibrates your helmet which then vibrates the other guys helmet and air inside it. A bit like a [tin-can telephone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin_can_telephone).

Comment: indeed, would the sound be like you are under water or like a sound you hear be-hide a wall

Comment: I'm not sure about this, I assume the sound would be like if you are inside a tin-can on earth & someone makes contact-noises with the hull. The hull's vibration isn't dampened like it would be under water and the sound distribution inside is the same as on earth. By the way, in ISS, there's a lot of background noise due to fans and other machinery in most parts (just watch one of those videos where astronauts show a tour of the ISS).

Comment: Another thing you might want to research are interviews with cosmonauts that were aboard during the [Mir-Progress collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progress_M-34). That is an actual collision of two space crafts with people inside.

Comment: Found a [video where the astronauts/cosmonauts talk about the collision](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=tM7fTLLmgbk#t=232s).

Comment: very useful i get the idea now, thank you :)

Comment: It would probably be amazingly loud too considering that the entire hull would reverberate making every surface of the ship, inside and out, into a giant speaker (Unless internal bulkheads were specifically designed to isolate external vibrations like engine noise in which case it would just be Very Loud.

Answer (score 3):

If you have ever been in a fender bender, you'll know that it is loud.  Outside the car, people hear a little bang.  When you're inside the car, all of the metal of the frame and body shakes from the impact and you know that you've been hit.

Your passengers will hear the collision.  The may not be able to hear anything else.

Answer (score 2):

The collision happened outside but the vibrations are happening inside the ship. The sound would travel through the air in your ship. Passengers would hear it.